# flask sqlite cannot delete rows from database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I cant seem to delete rows from sqlite database when using flask

```
@app.route('/deletePath',methods=['POST'])
    def deletePath():
        if 'toDelPathIndex' in request.form:
            pathIndex = request.form['toDelPathIndex']
            if not isInt(pathIndex):
                    errorMessage="Given Path Index "+pathIndex+" is not valid"
                    return render_template('addPath.html',error=errorMessage)

            cur = g.db.cursor()
            cur.execute('select id,ParentDir from Path')
            rows=cur.fetchall()
            found=0
            for row in rows:
                    if int(pathIndex) == row[0]:
                            Dir=row[1]
                            found = 1
            if found == 0:
                    errorMessage="Given Path Index "+pathIndex+" is not present in database"
                    return render_template('addPath.html',error=errorMessage)
            g.db.execute('delete from Path where id=' + pathIndex)
            g.db.commit()
            g.db.execute('delete from SnippetDirs where ParentDir=?',(Dir,))
            g.db.commit()
            return redirect(url_for('addPath_GET'))
    else:
                    errorMessage="Please give me a path index to try and delete"
                    return render_template('addPath.html',error=errorMessage)
```

More specifically this line

```
g.db.execute('delete from SnippetDirs where ParentDir=?',(Dir,))
```

is not working as expected because the size of the database is not decreasing
whereas this line

```
g.db.execute('delete from Path where id=' + pathIndex)
```

is executing correctly and deleting the required row from one of the table.

I dont know what i am doing wrong

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `Dir` when `if int(pathIndex) == row[0]:` is false?

Comment: Control does not go that line when int(pathIndex) == row[0]: is false, it just prints an error message.